# Passively Logging React App Performance in Production

Tags: performance, reactjs, logging, monitoring, production

I'm wondering if there are any utilities/patterns/paradigms/standards for monitoring React applications in production.

I've seen a lot of documentation about React performance debugging that recommends the Chrome Dev Tools (which are great, but aren't a passive way to monitor end user performance)

How could I log data to know how long users are waiting for components to mount or render?

The only thing I've thought of so far is creating a `Loggable[Pure]Component` that extends `React.[Pure]Component` whose constructor, `componentWillMount/Update`, and `componentDidMount/Update` methods log render/mount times to a server. Then, components I want to monitor can extend these components and, if need be, call `super()` in the lifecycle methods before doing their own work. To specifically know which components these metrics go to, I'd have to expose a method in the `Loggable[Pure]Component` class that does something silly like `setUniqueId` and then each derived class would have to call it in the constructor.

This all seems terrible and I'm very much hoping there are some things people out there have implemented, but I haven't found anything thus far.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look at some APM tools, they handle the frontend monitoring, and the backend monitoring as well. They all support react, and folks use these all the time for that use case. It really depends on your goals in the monitoring, are you doing this for fun? Do you have a startup? Are you working for a large enterprise? There are 3 major players in this market.

AppDynamics - Enterprise APM, handles the most complex apps. Unified product offering delivered SaaS or on-premises. Has deep database, server, and other monitoring.
Dynatrace - Enterprise APM, handles complex apps well. Fragmented portfolio, but the SaaS product is good. The SaaS product has limited depth in some ways. Handles server and cloud infrastructure monitoring well.
New Relic - Easy and cheap(er than others), not as in-depth as some other options. Tends to be popular with small companies. Does a good job monitoring cloud infrastructure services.

These products all do what you are looking for, but it depends on your goals with the data and how you plan to analyze it.

If you want something free and less functional there are ways to do this with open source, but you'll have to stand up and manage a pretty complex stack. Here is one option.

Check out boomerang, which can log/extract the metrics you are looking for, it doesn't "understand" react, but it should work. This data can be posted to many different systems. The best suited is likely the ELK stack (open source log analytics, and more). Here is one of several examples which marries these two together to provide analysis of the browser performance https://github.com/naukri-engineering/NewMonk